# I can't find my java .class file while running the program from the command line ( class do not belong to any package)

Tags: java, cmd, compilation

**Command line:**

```
C:\Users\s\Documents\Documents>javac hello.java

C:\Users\s\Documents\Documents>java hello
Error: Could not find or load main class hello
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

Comment: Thank you, people, for your help. I understood the cause. I saved my file with a different name than the class name, which caused this problem.